# Setup apache server for labelme

Tags: server, apache2, localhost

I need to run a apache server locally in order to use the program [labelme](https://github.com/npinto/labelme). However I'm not able to do it.

There is a description saying that I need to place my folder containing "index.html" inside `/var/www/html`.

However I need to run the website located in the local folder `~/libs/labelme`.

I also followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389399/setup-localhost-site-in-apache) instruction from similar askubuntu-question. But it doesn't work for me. The browser just displays nothing when I try to reach that project-page.

I'm a novice in apache, so I don't even know if the problem lies with the way I configured apache or if the problem comes from `labelme`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: move **~/libs/labelme** to **/home/labelme** and try http://askubuntu.com/questions/389399/setup-localhost-site-in-apache 1 st answer

Answer (score 1):

Found some better documented version of the [labelme](https://github.com/CSAILVision/LabelMeAnnotationTool) code with better documentation. These is the full list of options that one needs to make the apache server run correctly (modify `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`)

```
   <Directory "/var/www/LabelMeAnnotationTool">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
       AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
       AllowOverride all
       Require all granted
       AddType text/html .shtml
       AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
       DirectoryIndex index.shtml
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/

nano 000-default.conf
```

**search** for `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` (ctrl+w type /var/www/html)

**replace** `/var/www/html` with `/home/labelme` **move lableme to /home/ directory**

**save** the file 000-default.conf (ctrl+x and the y > enter)

**edit** `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file

add below lines after:

```
<Directory /home/labelme/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

restart apache2 web server:

```
service apache2 restart
```

And enter below URL into your browser

http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost/

**OR**

Comment: Strangely I get an `Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server - Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80` Error now.

Comment: I just looked again into the `README` of `labelme` and it says: `* Enable authconfig in Apache so that server side includes (SSI) will
  work.  This will allow SVG drawing capabilities.` and also `* Allow perl/CGI scripts to run.`
Maybe thats why it is forbidden. However I don't know how to activate them. In case that's really the problem I might also update my question

Comment: updated answer. edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file.

Comment: Actually there were a ton of more options needed to make it run as I found out in some newer version of the code. I will add it as a separate answer. Still thanks for your help